# Current request is not a multipart request with Postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman, rest

I have this class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@Slf4j
public class FileController extends ResourceController {

    private final FileUtils fileUtils;

    public FileController(JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil,
            UserService userService, FileUtils fileUtils) {
        super(jwtTokenUtil, userService);
        this.fileUtils = fileUtils;
    }

    @PostMapping("/uploadFile")
    public void uploadFile( @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                            @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String authHeader) {
...
}
```

but when I call the endPoint with Postman selecting binary as body I have this error:

```
"org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValueInternal(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:210)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:193)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:114)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.
```

Comment: You could try some of the things suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983296/the-current-request-is-not-a-multipart-request-spring-mvc) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64158746/current-request-is-not-a-multipart-request-spring-boot-and-postman-uploading-js).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Body as "form-data" in Postman. Then in the "KEY" column select file instead of text, set the key as `file` and select the file to upload. Additionally, make sure that in the Headers tab you don't have any manually added `Content-Type`. Postman will derive it based on Body tab.

[image: Check here a Postman example]